# Why doesn't the Silver Surfer live the life of a recluse?

Tags: marvel, silver-surfer

I only know the early Silver Surfer comics, so maybe later issues deal with that question, yet considering how he is depicted in the earliest episodes (in constant dismay because of the narrow-mindedness of the human race), I don't see any other reason except character concept (the over-idealistic knight in shining armor) why the Silver Surfer shouldn't live a life in solitude in order to prevent himself from overwhelming despair.

So: What keeps him from enjoying his own company exclusively?

Comment: "Man, I've got phenomenal cosmic power.  I'm SOOOOO bored living in this cave."

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're trying to prove a negative. I think we need to judge him by what he has done and not by what he hasn't done. He despairs but he doesn't give up; that's what makes him heroic.

Answer (score 4):

as far as I understand the surfer, he's a contemplative, restless, adventurous free spirit who grew to resent humanity because he was imprisoned on Earth by Galactus and because most of humanity was fairly petty. He still is heroic and will protect the earth if necessary.

he's an explorer but he's not a recluse as your question implies (please, correct me if I'm wrong) as he's had several love interests over the years; Shalla-Bal, Nova, Alicia Masters etc

I guess he's a rugged individual which is part of his appeal...

I hope this helps,

Comment: I think you have misread the question - the question is asking why the Surfer DOESN'T live as a recluse, not why he does.

Comment: as I tried to explain, he doesn't live as a recluse because that's not his personality. He (originally) was a peaceful, restless adventurer who rejected (boring) utopia. Imprisoned on earth, he grew to resent humans and resonated more with animals AND I agree with you; it would be pretty boring to have the hero live in a cave...